# Same character used in several Lexer rules?

Tags: antlr4

I have (probably) a quite simple question. I am writing a ANTLR grammer to evaluate dice expressions. With this I would like to parse something like `4d6` as well as `4d6d2`. The first means "roll 4 six-sided dice" and the second means "roll 4 six-sided dice an drop the 2 lowest". My current grammer is:

```
grammar Dice;
start : dice ; 

dice : NUMBER? DSEPERATOR NUMBER ( KEEP | DROP NUMBER )?;

KEEP : 'k';
DROP : 'd';
DSEPERATOR : [dD];
NUMBER : [0-9]+;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines
```

I seem to be getting a problem with the definition of `KEEP` and `DSEPERATOR` as they both use the letter `d`. The parser stops after the first `NUMBER` in the `dice` expression. What is the work around here? What do I have to change in my grammar?

Answer (score 0):

The implicit structure being parsed is

```
e - number of executions
d - type of object
s - number of object sides
o - op to apply*
a - number of op applications*
```

So, the match rule is:

```
 decode : e d s ( o a )? ;
```

Consolidating numbers and expanding:

```
 decode : e=NUM type s=NUM ( op a=NUM )? ; // label for convenience
 type   : dice | .... ;
 op     : drop | .... ;
 dice   : D ;
 drop   : D ;

 NUM    : [0-9]+ ;
 D      : 'd'    ;
```